# Set Local Storage at loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, local-storage

Here is my situation
I have this page here: https://wizquiz.gr/courses-list/all-courses/lesson/01-quiz-a-dim-glossa which loads on an iframe the page here: https://wordwall.net/embed/play/10746/628/2302
I need when the page loads the input box to be filled with the First & Last Name of the user who is logged in.
When I check, using Chrome console on the Application tab I see that the Local Storage / https://wordwall.net has the keys **settinguser_forename** & **settinguser_surname** w/o any value. Now if I manually set them I can achieve what I want. The name input box of the iframe is filled with inputed strings.
I have searched and I couldn't find any Javascript code that I can use to set these two key values on page load.
Is that possible?
My javascript experience is very limited...

Could you please write some code that I can test?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Allowing you to affect the localStorage data of someone else’s website would be a major security flaw, like allowing you to freely change data in their DB

Comment: You are right but I just want to automate the input of First & Last Name so that the user will not have to do it and since this website keeps some statistics under the Name of the user to be able to display the correct statistics for that name. If every time the user inputs different name then the statistical data will not be accurate. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Anyone that came across to a similar problem? Anyone that has found a solution? Any ideas to try??